# ACF date-picker add one year

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datepicker, advanced-custom-fields

I have a question, i'm using ACF 4.4.12.1 with wordpress and i would like to add 1 year to a date create with a repeater field.

In front office I display one date called "first-date" like that :

`<?php the_sub_field('first-date'); ?>` (it's a field type date-picker)

Now i want to display another date called that display the same date that "first-date" but with adding one year.

I'm trying to do something like that :

```
<?php
echo $date_debut    =   the_sub_field('first-date');
$date_expire    =   $date_debut;

$nbre=365;
$tmp=split('-', $date_expire);
$jour = $tmp[2]; 
$mois = $tmp[1]; 
$annee = $tmp[0]; 

$date_expiration = mktime($jour, $mois , $annee)+ 24*3600*$nbre;
echo '<br />'.date("d-m-Y", $date_expiration);
```

But I recover the value 01-01-1971
Can somebody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: `+ 24*3600*$nbre` - this is nonsense. Not every year has 365 days, and not every day has 24*3,600 seconds ... Just passing `$annee+1` as third parameter to mktime to trivial for your taste, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// $date_debut = 17/01/2018 for example
$date_debut = get_sub_field('first-date'); 

// Need to replace the slash by a dash
$date_debut = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$date_debut));

$date_expiration = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(" + 1 year", $date_debut ));

echo '<br />'.$date_expiration; 
// Display: 17-01-2019
```

And you have call `the_sub_field()` while you must use `get_sub_field()` because you want to **retrieve** the value and **not display it** directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it now recovers the value 01-01-1970.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump of get_sub_field('first-date'); and send the result here ?

Comment: sorry you just need to echo like this : echo '<br />'.$date_expiration;

Comment: I've got the same result 01-01-1970
And the result for var_dump is string(10) "17/01/2018"

Comment: okay i got it, this one works with your date : replace the line where we defined $date_expiration by : $date_expiration = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(strtotime($date_debut) . " + 1 year")); The reason is that the format "d/m/Y" is not supported by the date() function.

Comment: I don't understand now i've got 09-01-2019 while my $date_debut is 17/01/2018. So it's like $date_debut is the date of today...

Comment: Okay, i was missing something sorry ... it was "laborieux". Get the new code from my answer

Comment: Perfect! Thanks you very much! "Merci"